# <h1> followed by <div display: block> => no break line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, line-breaks

I'm removing most `<br>` from my HTML and trying to replace it with CSS. I've tried several techniques but none on them worked for me, what am I doing wrong ?

- Using Bootstrap 4, I've try adding the class `d-block` to my elements (**h1** and the following **div**),
- I've tried adding margin/padding bottom with CSS,
- or, as in Bootstrap documentation, embed it into `<span>` and add the same classes (`d-block p-2`)
- I've also tried adding CSS to `<h1>`, such as :

```css
.h1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.h1::after {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h1 class="d-block">Portfolio</h1>

<!-- Mosaic buttons -->
<div class="d-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="all">ALL</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="demo">SOUND DESIGN</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="album">MUSIC</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="samplepack">SAMPLEPACKS</button>
</div>
```

On StackOverflow, the snippet works fine, but here's the result I've locally [image: 2 blocks on the same line] (can't manage to reproduce it here)

I'm expecting the buttons to sit **under** the `<h1>` tag (instead of on its right)
Here's the website before I remove all the 
 (slow and bugged) : https://staging-det-music.herokuapp.com/

If anyone is interested, the git repo: https://gitlab.com/kawsay/det

What am I missing  ? Any help would be gratefully received !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's the problem..

Comment: When I run the code snippet, the buttons are under the `<h1>` title.

Comment: I'll edit my post to make it more clear then.
The problem is that the <div> containing the <button> is sitting next to the <h1> tag (at the right). I'd like it to be at the bottom. (as the snippet, which doesn't really illustrate my problem)

Comment: *which doesn't really illustrate my problem* --> so you have to edit to illustrate the issue or there is no issue for us

Comment: I try to reproduce the behaviour I've locally, let me a moment (I though it'd illustrate it, but I was wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to display buttons in column

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="all">ALL</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="demo">SOUND DESIGN</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="album">MUSIC</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="samplepack">SAMPLEPACKS</button>
</div>
```

if you want to display buttons next to each other

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="all">ALL</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="demo">SOUND DESIGN</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="album">MUSIC</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light filter-button mr-2" data-filter="samplepack">SAMPLEPACKS</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sumak thanks, if you would be kind enough to accept answer and give me vote up it would be great :)

Comment: Of course ! :)

 (I was trying to reproduce the behaviour I've locally to make my post a bit clearer). Have a great day !